# Как сделать выпадающие меню html css

Tags: html, css

Не могу сделать выпадающее меню, с ютуба, форумов смотрел, коды добавлял, но не получается

[Основной туториал](https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_dropdown.php)

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-Medium";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-MediumItalic";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-MediumItalic.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-Bold";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Bold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo2-BoldItalic";
    src: url("../fonts/Exo2-BoldItalic.ttf");
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url("../img/white-needle.png");
}
#block-body {
    width: 1035px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    height: auto;
}
header {
   width: 1035px; 
   height: 80px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
}
<!--#22B14C-->
#block-content {
    width: 1035px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
}
.logo a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
    color:  #b2aeb2;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.use {
    color: white;
    
}
.web {
    color: #429595;
    background: white;
    padding: 2px; 
}
.logo p {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #22B14C;
}
.top-menu {
    width: 685px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 171px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:  "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #121313;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.top-menu ul li a:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #22B14C;
}
.block-top-auth {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 80px;
}

.block-top-auth p {
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    
}
.block-top-auth a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #121313;
    font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block-top-auth a:hover {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    color: #124f2e;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
}
nav ul ul li {
    min-width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Шапка для сайта</title>
</head>
<body>
 
    <div id="block-body">

     <header>

     <!--// разметка для логотипа -->

       <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
          <!-- <span class="use">Вкус</span><span class="web">Няшка</span>-->
        </a>   
       <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>    
       </div>  

       <!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

       <nav class="top-menu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Каталог</a></li>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">fdfd</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">fdddsf</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
             <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav> 

       <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

       <div class="block-top-auth">
         <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>  
         <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>  
       </div>  
         
     </header>

      <div id="block-content"></div>  
        
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На вашем месте я бы добавил ссылки на ютуб-туториалы/форумы, по которым Вы пытались написать данный код. Ссылка делается так: `[текст](ссылка)`

Comment: https://html5css.ru/edithtm/index.php

Comment: Ссылка пустая, для того, что бы редактировать вопрос есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1364960/edit)

Comment: https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_css_dropdown.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил меню у "Каталог"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Шапка для сайта</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
   @font-face {
font-family: "Exo2-Medium";
src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Exo2-MediumItalic";
src: url("../fonts/Exo2-MediumItalic.ttf");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Exo2-Bold";
src: url("../fonts/Exo2-Bold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Exo2-BoldItalic";
src: url("../fonts/Exo2-BoldItalic.ttf");
}
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
background-image: url("../img/white-needle.png");
}
#block-body {
width: 1035px;
margin: 5px auto;
height: auto;
}
header {
   width: 1035px; 
   height: 80px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
}
<!--#22B14C-->
#block-content {
width: 1035px;
height: auto;
min-height: 500px;
}
.logo {
width: 200px;
float: left;
height: 80px;
}
.logo a {
display: block;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
color:  #b2aeb2;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.use {
color: white;

}
.web {
color: #429595;
background: white;
padding: 2px; 
}
.logo p {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #22B14C;
}
.top-menu {
width: 685px;
height: 80px;
float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul li a {
display: block;
width: 171px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:  "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #121313;
height: 55px;
padding-top: 25px;
cursor: pointer;

}
.top-menu ul li a:hover{
transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #22B14C;
}
.block-top-auth {
width: 100px;
float: left;
margin-left: 40px;
height: 80px;
}

.block-top-auth p {
margin-top: 12px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 8px;

}
.block-top-auth a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #121313;
font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}
.block-top-auth a:hover {
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
color: #124f2e;
}
nav ul ul .submenu-link{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:inherit;
}
nav ul ul li .submenu-link{
min-width:170px;
float:none;
display:list-item;
position: relative;
}


/* Стили меню */ 
.submenu-link {
display: block;
width: 171px;
background-color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #121313;
height: 80px;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
}   

.submenu-link:hover {
transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #22B14C;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.submenu-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.dropdown:hover .submenu-content {display: block;}
/*.dropdown:hover .submenu-link {background-color: #3e8e41;}*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block-body">
<header>
<!--// разметка для логотипа -->
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>   
    <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>    
</div>  
<!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

   <nav class="top-menu">
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="submenu-link">Каталог</button>
            <div class="submenu-content">
                <a href="#">fdfd</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdddsf</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
         <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 

   <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

   <div class="block-top-auth">
     <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>  
     <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>  
   </div>  
     
 </header>

  <div id="block-content"></div>  
    
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, нажмите галочку слева